# Is the square matrix of entries ranging from $1$ up to $n^2$ allways L.D.?

Tags: linear-algebra

Today I've encountered the $4\times4$ matrix with entries ranging from $1$ to $16$ column-wise, and by doing some math I've also found that this matrix has vectors which are linearly dependent (L.D.)

And from previous experience with linear algebra I also know that the $3\times3$ matrix with entries ranging from $1$ to $9$ line-wise is also composed by L.D. vectors.

Knowing this I've come with the following proposition.

For all square matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{N})$ given by $\{ a_{ij} \}$ such that $a_{ij}=n (i-1) + j$ $\forall i,j\in \{1,\dots, n\}$ the column vectors that form the matrix are always L.D. $\forall n\geq 3$.

But I do not know how to prove this argument right or wrong.

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Do you mean a matrix that lists the entries in order?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.

Comment: You should be careful with using non standard initialisms. LD can also mean lower diagonal (obviously not the case here). It is good form being a bit more descriptive with text than less.

Comment: If fact for $n \geq 2$, $\operatorname{rank} A = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n\times n$ matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&2&\cdots &n\\
n+1&n+2 &\cdots & 2n\\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
(n-1)n+1 & (n-1)n+2 &\cdots & n^2
\end{array}\right)$$
has determinant $0$ if $n\geq 3$ and nonzero for $n=1,2$. In particular, the rows (and columns) are linearly independent for $n\geq 3$.

Indeed, note that row $k$, $k\geq 2$, minus row 1 is equal to $\Bigl( (k-1)n\ (k-1)n\ \cdots\ (k-1)n\Bigr)$. So if $n\geq 3$, then elementary row operations yield a matrix with two rows that are scalar multiples of each other. Hence, the determinant is $0$ (since elementary row operations do not change the rank).

For $n=1$, the matrix with single entry $1$ has determinant $1$. The $2\times 2$ matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\3&4\end{array}\right)$ has determinant $-2\neq 0$.

Taking transposes does not change the determinant, so the same is true for the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & n+1 & \cdots & (n-1)n+1\\
2 & n+2 & \cdots & (n-1)n+2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
n & 2n & \cdots & n^2
\end{array}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that each row of your matrix can be written as a linear combination of the two vectors $(1,2,\dots,n)$ and $(1,1,\dots,1)$.

Alternatively, verify that the first three rows $\vec r_1,\vec r_2, \vec r_3$ of your matrix satisfy
$$
\vec r_1 - 2\vec r_2  + \vec r_3 = 0.
$$